# What are methods for correction of experimental measurements?

Tags: data-analysis, rounding-error, truncation-error

I have experimental data series collected from sensors, and I have some problems because the data is obviously digitally distorted.

I don't know if it is a problem of rounding, or quantization, or truncation.

I had been looking for techniques for correction of that data.

I know about noise remotion on signals, but this is not exactly noise.

I had been searching for techniques to deal with this kind of problem, but I don't even know what is the terminology I need to use, so I failed.

The question is what are those kind of methods,for detection, identification and correction of data distortions caused by digitalization, rounding, truncation, quantization, aimed to make algorithmical corrections on the data.

Comment: This is not really mathematics, but it would help if you gave a specific example of what you mean by digitally distorted.

Comment: @copper.hat Analogic data is smooth. Digital data is discontinuous. I need to fix that discontinuity. I'm not asking for specific solutions to my data. This surely is mathematics, same as noise remotion. There should be an entire set of mathematical techniques for identification and correction of distortions in digital data, because it obviously is a common problem. I just don't know the therminology or the name of the mathematical branch which deal with it. I need to be told what branch of mathematics is the one I need to know. Or what is the name of the set of techniques commonly used.

Comment: Sampling introduces some errors, but it is not clear what you mean by 'fixing that discontinuity'.